# Google TV app with external libraries (jar)

Tags: android, google-tv

I am trying to run a simple app on the Google TV emulator.

The app has a jar, it is both in the build path and in the lib folder, it works on ICS and on Honeycomb 3.1 (tablet) but on the Google TV emulator, it crashes:

```
D/dalvikvm( 1707): DexOpt: 'Ljavax/jmdns/ServiceListener;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
```

As if the lib had already been loaded.

Anyone seen this before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I have seen this before. Google TV is using JMDNS for supporting software remote controls. When I included JMDNS in my own app it was always loading the classes from the version already installed on the device instead of my copy of the classes. I did all of my testing on a Google TV device and didn't use the emulator. The JMDNS version on Google TV also appears to be older than the latest version of JMDNS. In my code I called newer functions that failed on the device even though my copy of the JMDNS jar had those newer function signatures. It looks like the class loader on Android/Google TV is always picking up the system jar files before it gets to each app's jar files.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, this post helped me make progress on a GTV project I am working on that uses jmDNS.  I needed jmDNS to discover printers on the network and found out that the version of jmDNS that is built into GTV (version 2.1) does not discover printers.  I took the latest jmDNS version (at the time v3.4.1), changed the namespace names, recompiled into my code and ran my app on GTV.  Printer discovery now works great.  Of course, I can't ship my app with the altered version of jmDNS due to Apache licensing terms.  But, until the GTV code is updated to include a newer version of jmDNS, changing the namespace names in the jmDNS source code will allow you to develop your printer discovery app.

Comment: I'm not a lawyer, but I think the statement "I can't ship my app with the altered version of jmDNS due to Apache licensing terms" isn't correct. You should be able to use derived code with the Apache license with your product as long as you follow the redistribution portion of rhw license of course.